# 502 Bad Gateway exceptions from HTTP Trigger Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-502

I have HTTP trigger Azure Durable Function. On running this function, I see 502 Bad Gateway exceptions happening very frequently.

[image]

On looking 'Diagnose and solve problems', I see this:

502 errors: The HTTP Trigger limits at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#trigger---limits---limits may result in 502 errors being logged if you hit these limits.

This is `host.json` in my Azure Function:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Well … are you hitting the limits?

Comment: How do I check if this function is hitting the limits?

Comment: By default i think maximum runtime of a function is 5 minutes on consumption plan. You can change it to maximum of 10 minutes by editing the host.json file. Or you can put tbe funtion app in an app service plane where there is no tome limit

Answer (score 0):

As the users @*Skin* and @*thanzeel* specified that your function hitting the limits such as time-out, etc. and also same is mentioned in your last screenshot given:

[image]

If you open the link specified in above image i.e., [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#limits) of Azure Function Http Webhook Limits, check if your Function App:

- If hosted in consumption plan, increase its time-out value from **`host.json`** file and check.
- If Http Request Time is more than the consumption plan limit, go for durable functions - async patterns or scale the hosting plan such as premium or app service plan.
- Another cause of this issue is might due to Length Limits of Http Request or the URL.